# How do I install the dpkg-dev package? Requires Ubuntu ISO

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-sources

Please assist me in installing `dpkg-dev`. It requires me to
insert "ubuntu 12.04.1 precise pangolin i386". I did download
and burn the image onto a disk. Repeated the process..i.e.

1. type `sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev`
2. inserted the above mention disc as required
3. pressed 'enter' as required, but that's where nothing happens and my problem begun..

Any advice would be appreciated or please send me the exact image of the
above mentioned ubuntu image/iso file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm providing an answer, but can you include whether you are using a desktop/GUI installation or server/commandline?

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the online repositories instead of CD-ROMs

It's recommended to install packages from the official repositories available using the internet, rather than installing from (outdated) CD images.

1. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` with your favourite text editor, e.g.

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list # or vim / nano / joe - whatever you like
   ```
2. Comment out the lines starting with `deb cdrom:`. This means, prepending them with a `#` (hash). For example:

   ```
   deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
   deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
   ```

   Becomes

   ```
   # deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
   # deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
   ```
3. Check whether regular `deb http://...` or `deb ftp://...` are present in the file elsewhere. You should at least have some lines like

   ```
   deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
   deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
   ```
4. Update the sources.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
   ```
6. Install updates (you probably have a lot outstanding now that you haven't accessed the repostories online).

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # no, this won't upgrade to a new release
   ```

---

In case you still have issues locating the package, include the output of

```
apt-cache policy dpkg-dev
```

and

```
grep -vrE "(^#|^$)" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

in your question.